# How to get and show the best selling products in customer account page magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, best-seller

I wish to show best selling products in in my customer My **account page**.Please provide me a solution to get best selling products and display in home page.

I have getting account file from this path :

From below file I am getting frontend structure

```
/var/www/html/myproject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Magedelight_SMSProfile/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml
```

Below is the file from i'm getting code

```
/var/www/html/myproject/app/code/Magedelight/SMSProfile/Block/Account/Dashboard/Info.php
```

If anyone have idea how to get bestseller product and display in phtml file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is concept of show 12 bestsellers for last 3 month

You can change period and limits for your own

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Block/Bestsellers.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility as ProductVisibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory as BestsellersCollectionFactory;

/**
 * @method int getLimit()
 * @method $this setLimit(int $value)
 */
class Bestsellers extends AbstractProduct implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var BestsellersCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $reportCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $timezone;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $locale;

    /**
     * @var ProductVisibility
     */
    protected $productVisibility;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        BestsellersCollectionFactory $reportCollectionFactory,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        ProductVisibility $productVisibility,
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->reportCollectionFactory  = $reportCollectionFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->timezone                 = $timezone;
        $this->locale                   = $localeResolver->getLocale();
        $this->productVisibility        = $productVisibility;

        if (!isset($data['limit'])) {
            $data['limit'] = 12;
        }

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getProductCollection(): Collection
    {
        if ($this->collection === null) {
            $from = $this->timezone->date(
                new \DateTime('3 month ago', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')),
                $this->locale
            );

            $reportCollection = $this->reportCollectionFactory->create()
                ->setDateRange($from)
                // additional buffer of 10 products
                ->setPageSize($this->getLimit() + 10)
                ->load(false, true);

            $productIds = [];
            foreach ($reportCollection as $item) {
                $productIds[] = $item->getData('product_id');
            }

            $this->collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
            $this->collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);

            if (count($productIds) > 0) {
                $this->collection->getSelect()
                    ->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id,' . implode(',', $productIds) . ')'));
            }

            $this->collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->collection)
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->setPageSize($this->getLimit());

            $this->collection->load(false, true);
        }

        return $this->collection;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getIdentities(): array
    {
        $identities = [];
        foreach ($this->getProductCollection() as $product) {
            $identities[] = $product->getIdentities();
        }

        return $identities;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Acme\StackExchange\Block\Bestsellers" name="product-bestsellers"
                   template="Acme_StackExchange::bestsellers.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/templates/bestsellers.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Acme\StackExchange\Block\Bestsellers $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php $this
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

$type  = 'bestsellers';
$class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;
$image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
$title = __('Bestsellers');
$items = $block->getProductCollection();

$showAddTo         = true;
$showCart          = true;
$templateType      = ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
$canItemsAddToCart = false;

?>
<?php if ($items->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="block <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>">
        <div class="block-title title">
            <strong id="block-<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading" role="heading"
                    aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml($title) ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading">
            <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($type) ?>">
                <ol class="products list items product-items">
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
                        <li class="item product product-item">
                            <div class="product-item-info">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */
                                '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                                <a href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                   class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                    <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                                </a>
                                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                    <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a
                                                class="product-item-link"
                                                title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                                href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                    </strong>

                                    <?= /* @noEscape */
                                    $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                                    <?php if ($templateType): ?>
                                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart): ?>
                                        <?php // phpcs:disable ?>
                                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                            <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                        <?php if (!$_item->getTypeInstance()->isPossibleBuyFromList($_item)): ?>
                                                            <button
                                                                    class="action tocart primary"
                                                                    data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"}}'
                                                                    type="button"
                                                                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        <?php else : ?>
                                                            <?php
                                                            /** @var $viewModel PreparePostData */
                                                            $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
                                                            $postArray = $viewModel->getPostData(
                                                                $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)),
                                                                ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]
                                                            );
                                                            $value     = $postArray['data'][ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED];
                                                            ?>
                                                            <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                                                  data-product-sku="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                                                                  action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                                                  method="post">
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="product"
                                                                       value="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                                                       (int)$_item->getEntityId() ?>">
                                                                <input type="hidden"
                                                                       name="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                                                       ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                                       value="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                                                       $value ?>">
                                                                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                                <button type="submit"
                                                                        title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </form>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->isAvailable()): ?>
                                                            <div class="stock available">
                                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php else: ?>
                                                            <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                            <?php if ($showAddTo): ?>
                                                <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary"
                                                     data-role="add-to-links">
                                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')): ?>
                                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php // phpcs:enable ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled() && $_item): ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_item->getSku()) ?>"
            }
        }
    }

        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```